# Finding the top 10/15/20 percent (excel 2016 or google sheets)

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I have an alphabetical list of students in Column A.  In Column E is the total number of award dollars they have earned.  I need to find the top 10% award earners, top 11-15%, and then the top 16-20%.  I really would rather not reorder them based on award dollars.  Help!

Comment: Can you share the trouble you faced when (after select data) using : [ Home > Conditional Fomatting > Top 10% ] ?

Answer (score 0):

Top 10% are green, 10.01-15% are blue, 15.01%-20% are yellow.

Cell formulas
G2 = COUNTA(A3:A31)   *how many students in the list*
H2 = COUNTED*10/100   *how many will be in top 10%*
I2 = COUNTED*15/100   *how many will be in top 15%*
J2 = COUNTED*20/100   *how many will be in top 20%*
F3:F31 = RANK(E3,AWARD)  *ranking of each student*

Name ranges
AWARD = E3:E31
COUNTED = G2

Conditional Formatting for column F ('RANK')
Value < H2, Bold Green on Light Green *(top 10%)*
Value > H2 < I2, Bold Blue on Light Blue *(between 10.01% & 15%)*
Value > I2 < J2, Dark Yellow on Light Yellow *(between 15.01% and 20%)*

[image: example spreadsheet]